# How to load datasets for use globally in a shiny app using the golem framework

Tags: r, shiny, golem

I am creating a shiny app using golem (I am just learning to use the golem framework). Usually, when developing a shiny app, if I have a dataset that I want to be available globally (ie available to all ui and server parts of the app), I load it in the Global.R file. However, with golem there doesn't seem to be a Global.R file. Where am I supposed to load in datasets to make them available throughout the app? The same applies to (e.g.) a list of hex colors which I would use throughout the app or any other global definitions.